# Ruby Syntax - Block After if statement (Devise Source)

Tags: ruby, devise

I'm having trouble wrapping my head around this if statement.  It has a conditional that is immediately followed by a block.  What does this mean / why would you choose to do this?  This is from the Devise source code.

```
   if validate(resource){ hashed = true; resource.valid_password?(password) }
     remember_me(resource)
     resource.after_database_authentication
     success!(resource)
   end
```

Full class is here: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/strategies/database_authenticatable.rb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Devise::Strategies::Authenticable#validate`](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/strategies/authenticatable.rb#L35) accepts a block.

The code you posted is a short form of:

```
validated = validate(resource) do
  hashed = true
  resource.valid_password?(password)
end

if validated
  remember_me(resource)
  resource.after_database_authentication
  success!(resource)
end
```

Why would they write it this way?—No idea. Possibly due to the lack of rubocop.

Comment: It didn't even occur to me that the method could take a block.  Thanks!

Comment: @Trinculo: even if a method doesn't take a block you can nevertheless always pass one.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev - Good to know, thanks.  I'm still learning little bits and pieces even after a few years :-)

Comment: @JimU “It [the block passed] will get executed if `validate` executes a `yield` statement.”—strictly speaking, this is wrong.